# Cannot break out of while loop in java

Tags: java

i am unable to break out of while loop, please check out and recommend me how to do it

```
public class Admin {
boolean exit=false;
public Admin(){
    while (!exit){
    printInstructions();
    }
}
public void printInstructions(){
    System.out.println("check 1 to print hi");
    System.out.println("check 2 to exit");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice=scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    choose(choice);
}
public void choose(int choice){
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("hi");
            break;
        case 2:
            exit=true;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

i expected the code to stop executing but on the contrary it is running a number of times. but the while loop is running over and over. i wonder why?

Comment: Put a `break` in the `while` loop. Not in your `switch` statement in an unrelated method. Actually, you need a `break` there too. But it's still unrelated to your `while` loop. Actually, where do you invoke `new Admin()`?

Comment: Don't keep recreating your `System.in`. Create one Scanner based on this at the start, and then use it throughout your program.

Comment: actually this is an simplified code of the actual version of the code as it was too redundant,but the idea was to implement nested while loops similar to this one , which can keep on running till the condition is satisfied.(int he project these while loops are welcoming the user to a portal over and over again so that he can provide operations further)

Comment: Post code that compiles, runs and reproduces the problem, a [mcve].

Comment: I prefixed the code with `import java.util.*;
interface Code {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        new Admin();
    }
}` and it **works for me**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine that you are trying to decomposite your code to smaller methods/functions. But it will be better if your functions will be interact with each other. To make it possible your functions must return some value as a result of the execution:

```
// returns exit flag
public bool choose(int choice){
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("hi");
            return false;
        case 2:
            return true;
    }
}

// print instructions and return the choose
public int printInstructions(){
    System.out.println("check 1 to print hi");
    System.out.println("check 2 to exit");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice=scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    return choice;
}


public Admin(){
    while (!exit){
      int result = printInstructions();
      exit = choose(result);
    }
}
```

I write code in the browser so it can still have some small mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `break` or `return` in both `switch` statements to leave the switch altogether. After that it will return to `while` statement, evaluate `boolean exit` and exit the `loop` when it's `false`.

```
 public void choose(int choice){
    switch(choice){
      case 1:
        System.out.println("hi");
        break;
      case 2:
        exit=true;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure, it's running fine as expected in my computer. Where are you calling `new Admin()`? How are you testing this? it's actually working even without break statement on second switch.

Comment: thanks man actually it was recalling the entire constructor over again (as it was placed inside another while loop), all i had to do was place a break statement inside the other class where i was calling it.